# Git : fatal: Couldn't find remote ref my_repo

Tags: git, version-control

I have just started using git for version control; coming from svn background.

I created a branch for making some changes, with name `my_repo`. I dont remember If I used `-b` option or not.

```
~MyProject$ git checkout -b my_repo or git checkout my_repo
```

After that I made some changes, committed them and pushed them. I am sure my changes are pushed because it shows up in the log

```
~MyProject$ git branch 
  dev
* my_repo
  master

~MyProject$ git log
commit a2104d193c8642360e3a09cf5260739fb25
Author: Adam Douglas <adam.douglas@mycompany.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 3 12:18:19 2015 +0530

    Services and controllers

commit b4a225ed1e69de39566c088c8d285936ae4
Author: Adam Douglas <adam.douglas@mycompany.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 1 17:28:26 2015 +0530

    DB Changes

~MyProject$ git status
On branch my_repo
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Scraper/${sys:catalina.base}/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

However, when I try to pull changes, i get thee following error.

```
~/Documents/SourceCode/IntelliJ/MyProject$ git pull origin my_repo
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref my_repo
~/Documents/SourceCode/IntelliJ/MyProject$ fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Why is this happening ? I can see them in the logs.

Comment: Regardless of the problem here, naming a branch `my_repo` can lead to much confusion.

Comment: *I am sure my changes are pushed because it shows up in the log* pushes are not logged, commits are

Comment: @TimCastelijns : Thanks, Tim. My mistake.

Comment: @Jubobs : I am just starting out. Will keep this in mind in future.

Comment: @LearningToDesign what's the output of `git ls-remote`?

Comment: ccd4953cf33da5aa54944a034fc3e76b319d0056 HEAD
36f96cbe886024b2074620c30086c3358f23269d refs/heads/dev
ccd4953cf33da5aa54944a034fc3e76b319d0056 refs/heads/master
ccd4953cf33da5aa54944a034fc3e76b319d0056 refs/heads/packman
36f96cbe886024b2074620c30086c3358f23269d refs/heads/production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it is clear that the branch `my_repo` does not exist in your remote repository. This could mean one of two things:

1. You've create a branch on your local repository and (possibly) committed changes too. However, you haven't pushed these changes to the remote repository.
2. It could also mean that someone who controls the remote repo used a `git push --delete origin my_repo`.

In any case you'll have to first `push` the changes to the remote repository using `git push origin my_repo`